# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un metodo para devolver los atributos de un objeto en Strings?

Tags: javascript, string, object

Tengo una clase empleado que tiene los siguientes atributos:

```
function Empleado(dni, nombre, nacimiento,ingreso_empresa) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nacimiento = nacimiento;
        this.ingreso_empresa = ingreso_empresa;
}
```

¿Cómo podría imprimir un objeto de esta clase con strings?

Lo he intentado de esta manera pero no funciona:

```
 Empleado.prototype.listarEmpleado = function() {

        return "DNI: " + this.dni +
            " \nNombre: " + this.nombre +
            " \nAño de nacimiento: " + this.nacimiento +
            " \nAños en la empresa: " + this.ingreso_empresa +
            " ";
    };

    var e1 = new Empleado('80826442A', 'Gerardo Martinez Iglesias', 1975, 12);
    listarEmpleado(e1);
```

La consola del navegador no muestra ningún error

Comment: tofo objeto tiene su ´.toString()' con solo hacer e1.toString() tienes

Answer (score 0):

El método listarEmpleado ` está dentro de Empleado.
Bueno, dentro del prototype de Empleado.
Y aquí estás creando un objeto de Empleado:

`var e1 = new Empleado('80826442A', 'Gerardo Martinez Iglesias', 1975, 12);`

Entonces tendrías que mandar el mensaje al objeto `e1`
`e1.listarEmpleado();`

Comment: Gracias, ya se muestran los atributos